# Aplicação C# no visual Studio não conecta ao banco Sql via rede

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Estou enfrentando um problema com a minha aplicação.
Fiz a aplicação sem nenhum erro, gerei o instalador, porém quando vou executá-lo, ele não conecta ao banco via rede, porém no Visual Studio ele conecta.

Já fiz a configuração de habilitar **TCP/IP** e **PIPES**, coloquei a porta *1433* e uma secundária no *Sql*, adicionei a saída e entrada no *firewall* das portas, já ativei o compartilhamento no windows, e etc...

Obs.: Eu consigo conectar da minha máquina via Sql o banco no servidor, porém a aplicação executável não consegue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Victor, poderia colocar sua connection string?

Comment: poderia colocar sua string de conexão para nos analisar? e verifica se se app.config está com o mesmo endereço de conexão da sua string de conexão.

Comment: Você precisa recuperar o código de erro (depurar) ao exibir a mensagem "ERRO COM BANCO DE DADOS!". Isso vai ajudar a identificar a causa do problema.